# Como obtener la memoria fisica y disponible rapidamente? (Windows)

Tags: sql-server, windows, manejo-de-memoria

Quisiera obtener la memoria física total y disponible de Windows para almacenarlas en una tabla de SQL Server o por CMD y enviarlas en un informe. Lo ideal seria que en el CMD se mostrara algo asi

```
Memoria Total    Memoria Disponible
3,509            1,352 MB
```

El systeminfo muestra algo que ayuda:

```
C:\Windows\system32>systeminfo |find "física"
Cantidad total de memoria física:          3,509 MB
Memoria física disponible:                 1,352 MB
```

Pero quisiera verlo en formato tabular para poder almacenarlo como registros en SQL Server y enviar un informe. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: en que lenguaje? muestranos que has intentado

Comment: y además del lenguaje, ¿en que sistema operativo?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Camilo. Por favor edita la pregunta en el enlace que se encuentra al pie que dite **editar**, agrega la información relevante para comprender tu problema y ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ya Camilo editó la pregunta y queda claro (por lo menos para mi) que es lo que necesita y tengo una respuesta. Pero la pregunta está en espera y no me deja responder. ¿se podría abrir la pregunta de nuevo?.

Comment: @CamiloBernal gracias por avisarme. Por favor para estos casos, te recomendaría que coloques una bandera en la pregunta, selecciona la última opción *se necesita la intervención de un moderador* y en la caja de texto redactas la situación para trabajar en ella.

Answer (score 1):

Camilo, si lo que quieres es tener los datos de memoria disponible desde SQL, puedes utilizar esta consulta:

```
 select 
total_physical_memory_kb TamanoTotalMemoriaFisicaDisponible,
available_physical_memory_kb MemoriaFisicaDisponible,
available_page_file_kb CantidadTotalArchivoPaginacionNoUsado,
system_cache_kb CantidadTotalMemoriaCacheSistema,
system_memory_state_desc
from sys.dm_os_sys_memory
```

Con esto te mostrará varios datos interesantes de la memoria del equipo.
Ahora, si quieres volcar estos resultados a una tabla... puedes modififcar la consulta asi:

```
select  
total_physical_memory_kb TamanoTotalMemoriaFisicaDisponible,
available_physical_memory_kb MemoriaFisicaDisponible,
available_page_file_kb CantidadTotalArchivoPaginacionNoUsado,
system_cache_kb CantidadTotalMemoriaCacheSistema,
system_memory_state_desc
into {nombre_de_la_tabla}
from sys.dm_os_sys_memory

select * from {nombre_de_la_tabla}
```

De esta manera, accedes a los datos disponibles sobre la memoria del equipo desde SQL Server.

Puedes revisar la documentación de esta tabla del sistema: "***sys.dm_os_sys_memory***"  aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb510493.aspx

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Era justo lo que estaba buscando.Muchas gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: Genial, que bueno. No olvides valorar la respuesta como útil para que otros usuarios con las mismas dudas puedan identificar la respuesta como útil también.